# Example of a commutative square without a map between antidiagonal objects?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, exact-sequence

In an abelian category, can there be a commutative diagram of (vertical/horizontal) exact sequences
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> N @>>> M\\
@. @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> X @>>> Y\\
@. @VVV \\
@. 0
\end{CD}
$$

such that the following conditions are true?

- All named objects are nonzero.
- No morphisms between named objects are zero morphisms, including $N \to Y$ (implied by the previous and the diagram).
- There are no morphisms $X \to M$ or $M \to X$ that commute with the other maps.

(I am trying to "replace" $N$ by $\ker(N \to Y)$ and $Y$ by $\text{coker}(N \to Y)$ in the diagram to get back a commutative diagram of exact sequences, and my attempts so far require the existence of a compatible map between $X$ and $M$ in at least one direction, so I would like to figure out what happens if I have no such maps.)

**Original question**

"Modules with morphisms 0 -> N -> M and N -> X -> 0 but no compatible maps between M and X?"

I wish for three modules N, M, and X with exact sequences $0 \to N \to M$ and $N \to X \to 0$, but there are no such morphisms $M \to X$ or $X \to M$ which commute with the maps above.

(Not homework. I'm trying to replace X, N, and M in a bigger diagram so that X becomes 0 and N and M become something maximal (universal). If the above kind of module triples exists, I might be in trouble.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$, and $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to 0$. Then the only map in either direction between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is the zero map, since $\mathbb{Q}$ is torsionfree, and every quotient of $\mathbb{Q}$ is divisible.

Comment: It works. You showed me that my conditions are not enough for what I want. I will add another condition to the question.